# Converting $46°30'$ to radians

Tags: trigonometry

> Question: $46°30'$ to radians

To convert

From relation $180°=\pi$

$$(46\times30/60)\times\frac{\pi}{180}=0.4012$$

I'm getting wrong answer

Comment: What was your rationale for multiplying $46$ by $\frac{30}{60}$? Explain your thinking.

Answer (score 11):

It's a sum, not a product. $46^\circ$ $30'$  =$(46+30/60)^\circ$ and so

$$(46+30/60)\frac{\pi}{180}$$

Answer (score 9):

$$(46\color{red}+30/60)^\circ\times \frac{\pi}{180^\circ}=0.7069$$

Comment: +1 I love the idea of using color for emphasis. Just keep in mind that some people are color-blind.